# Fatal error: Call to a member function delete()

Tags: magento-1.7, import, delete

I want use the code, but i get a error:
"Fatal error: Call to a member function delete() on boolean in …"

The code:

```
public function _del()   
{
    umask(0);
    Mage::app();
    Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
    $f = file("var/import/sku.csv");

    foreach ($f as $line_num => $productSku) {
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', $productSku);
        $product->delete();
    }
}
```

With the sku.csv:

```
220112¬  
220111¬  
220114¬
```

Answer (score 3):

Tom,you need to upload product object by primary key.`loadByAttribute`() not capable for delete the product.

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', $productSku);



   /* product exit then the prooduct will be deleted
*/
    if($product->getId()):
        $id=$product->getId();
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);
        $product->delete();
     endif;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Amit. Ok. Works well with a single SKU '220114',but not with foreach. I get 
"Fatal error: Call to a member function getId() on a non-object in …" by the line "if($product->getId()): …"
Do you have a tipp?

Comment: first i check product is exit in system by using product id

Comment: yes i've checked it several times and try. I've try to change the sku's in the csv to '148568' … but it isn't work.

Answer (score 2):

`loadByAttribute()` could return a boolean. It will return the object on success and boolean `false` on failure (see `Mage_Catalog_Model_Abstract::loadByAttribute()`). So in your specific case the SKU could not be found. You need to factor the object first assigning it to a variable and then on the next line call `loadByAttribute()` to avoid this:

```
public function _del()   
{
    umask(0);
    Mage::app();
    Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
    $f = file("var/import/sku.csv");

    foreach ($f as $line_num => $productSku) {
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
        $product->loadByAttribute('sku', $productSku);
        if ($product->getId() && $product->delete()) {
            // Do something like `return true;`?
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `$product->getId() && $product->delete();`